# have problem with code it said "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stocks' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Try to learn React but have a problem when try to use "mapStateToProps"
it show error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stocks' of undefined"

---

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class StockList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getStocks();
  }

  render() {
    const { stocks } = this.props.stock;

    return (
      <Container>
        {stocks.map(({ _id, StockCode }) => ({ StockCode }))}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

StockList.propTypes = {
  getStocks: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  stock: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  //defind here
  stock: state.stock
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getStocks
  }
)(StockList);
```

I have a problem in this line

```
render() {
    const { stocks } = this.props.stock;
```

It said

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stocks' of undefined
```

Comment: can you show your reducers' `index.js`?

Comment: did you define constructor function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you extracting stocks from props isn’t right.

So Change

```
 const { stocks } = this.props.stock;
```

To

```
  const { stocks } = this.props;
```

With above change the functionality will work if stocks is always an array otherwise it won’t work

So, Initially the stocks prop will be undefined from redux store

So you need to do conditional check before doing map

Change

```
  {stocks.map(({ _id, StockCode }) => ({ StockCode }))}
```

To

```
  {Array.isArray(stocks) && stocks.map(({ _id, StockCode }) => ({ StockCode }))}
```

The above condition will check whether stocks is an array only the it does map

Or

```
  {stocks && stocks.map(({ _id, StockCode }) => ({ StockCode }))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error should be coming from your redux state, open your browser developer tools navigate to application tab, open local storage, check redux states and confirm if there is a key called stocks in stock, if there is no stocks then the error will probably be from your stock reducer